# What are my options to hunt Monotouch exceptions like "System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object that has been GC'ed"?

Tags: exception, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios

I'm getting some of those exceptions below. What are my options to track those issues down? I'm kind of lost with those as they happen sporadically only and ONLY on the device but never in the Simulator.

```
System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object that has been GC'ed ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Browser.FolderListController::.ctor(System.IntPtr)
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args, System.Object[] activationAttributes) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr klass) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr klass) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (IntPtr ptr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObjectWrapped (IntPtr ptr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime:GetNSObjectWrapped (intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Browser.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in .../Main.cs:15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a single, simple answer to that but I can share a way to help hunting them done:

Like @Miguel said such an exception means that the runtime is trying to re-surface an instance of `Browser.FolderListController`. That means that one, or many, instance(s) of `Browser.FolderListController` are being collected even if they will still be needed later.

Your first step should be to review the life cycle of every `Browser.FolderListController` instances. E.g.

- where they are created;
- where the calls occurs;
- where you `Dispose` them **manually** - which can conflict with any retain'ing MonoTouch try to do to help your;
- null'ed or removed from collections (i.e. removing references)...

Once you know the lifecycle you can:

- add a finalizer to `Browser.FolderListController` and set a breakpoint inside it. The finalizer are executed on a separate thread so it won't tell you where the last reference was removed - but it will tell you *approximately* when (at least not before *some* point);
- add the `.ctor(IntPtr)` constructor and add a breakpoint inside it. Again it won't give you an exact point (where it's being required) but it will tell you *approximately* when (at least not before *another* point);

Execute your application, get the crash and then look at what's going on between between those two points in time (compared to your lifecycle).

Comment: So you have an idea how I could force the problems? Of course they never happen for me...

Comment: You can *try* to provoke it more often by adding some `GC.Collect();` around, e.g. just after any call to `Browser.FolderListController`, and try to be as close as the original bug report is (e.g. I would assume **release** builds)

Comment: Are release builds more affected by GC problems?

Comment: No, but since you said "Of course they never happen for me..." I assumed this happens to customers, which would be using release builds. If you have trouble duplicating the issue (and believe me I know that feeling pretty well ;-) then you should aim, as close as possible, to the *real* configuration.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't exactly related to the OP's situation, but I got this error when loading a view from a nib and it turned out I hadn't setup the view class's constructor properly:

```
public MyView() : base()
{
    // Wrong!
}
```

You need to include the IntPtr parameter:

```
public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{

}
```

Comment: This was the solution when creating a new `UIViewController` in Mono and using it in a storyboard.

Comment: Had to add this constructor to fix my problem as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The above means that an object was created, passed down to Objective-C to be kept around and then it was garbage collected by Mono, and later re-surfaced to Mono on either a callback or some delegate invocation.

This usually means that in our code, we failed to catch a case where we needed to keep an explicit reference.  A test case for this would be useful as it would help us fix this in MonoTouch.

We have also developed a new technique to eliminate all of these problems at once, but the code is not ready for public use.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I know how it can happen but do you have a tipp how to find the issue in my case? I know it is a UITableViewCell I subclass...I cannot give you an example as it is happening too sporadic. But please tell me: shouldn't it happen in the Simulator mor often because GC is called constantly? I only see the effect on the device. I think it is a timing issue. The device simply is slower than the Simulator...but how the heck can I find out what exactly causes it??
Oh and: can you give me the basic idea of your "fix all" solution? Just a hint would be enough.