# Do I have to implement the IntPtr constructor of UIViewController?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios

This is kind of related to another question I posted : [What are my options to hunt Monotouch exceptions like "System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object that has been GC'ed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8344613/304870) .

I am getting crash reports from my testers and for almost all of my UIViewControllers I get erros that:

```
System.Exception: Selector invoked from objective-c on a managed object that has been GC'ed ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Browser.FolderListController::.ctor(System.IntPtr)
```

I am not aware that I'm doing something obviously wrong and I'm unable to track down the issues but I know that in none of the cases I override the **IntPtr** constructor. The question is: should I implement it? Will this make the issues go away? What will be the consequences if ObjC revives a GC'ed controller by using this constructor?

**EDIT:**

I found at least one cause if the problems by following Rolf's and Pupous suggestions and set up a Thread that GC's 10 times a second so that I could force the crash.
I make heavy use of **NSNotificationCenter**. I register my observers in `ViewDidLoad()` and unregister them in `ViewDidUnload()`.
However, the code that gets executed if a notification arrives `manipulates the controller's view`.
This means that there is a chance that the handler will trigger **AFTER** `ViewDidDisappear()`. And if the view happens to be GC'ed already, it would crash.
I fixed it by moving my subscription to the NSNOtificatioCenter into `ViewWillAppear()` and `ViewWillDisappear()`.

Comment: You can't override a constructor in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not override the IntPtr constructor.

You will only hide the problems in your code, not solve them.

Some (but not all) of the consequences of reviving a GC'ed controller is:

- All managed state will be gone. Any (managed) variables you had in the original controller will return to their original state (since you now have a new managed instance of the controller).
- The GC might have freed any other objects your controller had a reference too (this may include things such as delegates, which you can't recreate that easily. If a managed delegate is freed and then invoked, you'll end up with a pretty hard to track down native crash).
- Anything that depends on the managed and native objects being in sync will have undefined behavior (this may include code inside MonoTouch which you don't control).

In short: you need to find out exactly why the controller is freed, and prevent that from happening.

If you want a temporary workaround, create a static list and put all the instances of your controller in that list. This will use some memory (depending on how many objects you create of course), but you won't have to deal with undefined and unsupported behavior.

Comment: Im just wondering how I can possibly figure out the root cause...Can I find out what part of the ObjC causes it?

Comment: And also: it is happening totally randomly. Any idea how I could force these issues?

Comment: You can probably force the issue by running GC.Collect every X ms in a separate thread, and putting a Console.WriteLine in ~FolderListController will tell you exactly which GC is causing the controller to be freed.

Comment: I will try that. Will GC.Collect() actually do anything if there is no memory pressure?

Comment: GC.Collect (GC.MaxGenerations); will always run the GC (memory pressure isn't taken into account).

Comment: Meanwhile I figured out that the issue is mainly cause UITableViewSource.GetCell(). Something wants to resurrect the FolderListCell(), my subclass of UITableViewCell. I have a case where I always can reprouce it. Does UITableViewCell require the IntPtr constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue when I was pushing a new DetailViewController from my main RootViewController using IB Storyboard. Storyboard already had a segue push event Action created to a new Detail View all in Storyboard. However, I needed to dynamically push a different view based on the cell's content. Anyways, once I removed the segue push to the DetailView from Storyboard and programmatically tried to push the new view controller that's when I got the GC error.

I ended up scratching storyboard and just used plain xib files and was able to accomplish the same thing. I'm now suspicious about the GC going on with Storyboard.

Tools: Xcode 4.2.1 & MonoDevelop 2.8.5